# How to set ACL on a USB-device

Tags: debian, usb, acl

I'm new to acl's so this is blackmagic to me. But what I have is a camera that I want to talk to.

So I got a netbooted debian machine:

```
ulf@term13:~(0)$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10 (squeeze)
Release:    6.0.10
Codename:   squeeze
```

To that machine a I got a camera attached:

```
ulf@term13:~(0)$ lsusb | grep Nikon
Bus 001 Device 092: ID 04b0:0428 Nikon Corp. 
ulf@term13:~(0)$ ls -alF /dev/bus/usb/001/092 
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 189, 91 25 sep 10.05 /dev/bus/usb/001/092
```

Note the `+` at the end of the permissionstring `crw-rw-r--+`. That indicates that there is an [ACL](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#Access_Control_Lists_in_Linux) in work here:

```
ulf@term13:~(1)$ getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/092 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/092
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:knut:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Apparently the user knut has additional `rw` permissions here. **But how did he get them?**

I can set the same permissions to my user with `setfacl`. But whatever set like that will not be present after the camera has been reconnected. After toggling the camera on and off ones it actually gets *mounted* on another device:

```
ulf@term13:~(0)$ lsusb | grep Nikon
Bus 001 Device 093: ID 04b0:0428 Nikon Corp.
```

But the permissions for the new 093-device is the same as old 092 (without any extra permissions I added to the 092).

Is there some file where this is configured? This is setup by a sysadmin that is not present here any more so I need to fix it myself.

Comment: This is probably a hotplug or udev thing. However it might also be your desktop environment doing this. Try logging out of the GUI, switch to a console (ctrl-alt-F1), login there as the user, then plug the device again and check the ACLs now.

Comment: There is a good answer for the same question over at Superuser: http://superuser.com/a/989721/26811